# Rename Procedure in algorithm environment

Tags: formatting, algorithms, ieeetran, algorithm2e, algorithmicx

I use the following `algorithm` many times throughout my paper:

```
\begin{algorithm}[!t]
  \caption{Title}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]

    \Procedure{Graph}{$ \alpha, \beta $}    
    \State ...
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

How can I change `procedure` to appear `pseudocode` only for a **single** `algorithm` environment without affecting the entire paper?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the definition of `\algorithmicprocedure` in the scope of the desired `algorithm` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[!t]
\caption{Title}

\algrenewcommand\algorithmicprocedure{\textbf{pseudocode}}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\Procedure{Graph}{$ \alpha, \beta $}    
  \State ...
\EndProcedure

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[!t]
\caption{Title}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\Procedure{Graph}{$ \alpha, \beta $}    
  \State ...
\EndProcedure

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]